# JQuery toggle opacity with click

Tags: jquery, css, click, toggle, opacity

I have two divs (A and B) and two buttons and I'm trying to achieve this effect:
when I click on one button the opacity of div A increase, while opacity of div B decrease, and vice versa. But it seems to work only when decrease...
Can't understanfd what's wrong.

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="pippo"></div>
<div id="pluto"></div>
<div id="opacity">opacity</div>
<div id="opacity2">opacity2</div>


function changeOpacity() {


$( "#opacity" ).click(function() {
    var pippo = $('#pippo').css('opacity');
    var pluto = $('#pluto').css('opacity');
    $( "#pippo").css( "opacity", pippo + 0.1 );
    $( "#pluto").css( "opacity", pluto - 0.1 );
});
$( "#opacity2" ).click(function() {
    var pi = $('#pippo').css('opacity');
    var pl = $('#pluto').css('opacity');
    $( "#pippo").css( "opacity", (pi - 0.1)  );
    $( "#pluto").css( "opacity", (pl + 0.1)  );
    return false;
});
}
changeOpacity();
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/oLpe8yo1/4/)

Comment: `parseFloat()` when retrieving the CSS values - [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLpe8yo1/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `.css()` method does not return a number - it in fact gives you a string. So when you try to execute something like:

```
var pippo = $('#pippo').css('opacity');    
$( "#pippo").css( "opacity", pippo + 0.1 );
```

If `pippo` was say, 0.9, then `pippo + 0.1` would give you "0.90.1". The numerical 0.1 would be converted to a string, and you would get the concatenation of the two strings (since that is what the `+` operator does).

However, the reason why subtraction works, such as:

```
var pluto = $('#pluto').css('opacity');
$( "#pluto").css( "opacity", pluto - 0.1 );
```

Is because there is no subtraction operator for strings, and so `pluto` is automatically casted to a number.

To remedy this, consider using `parseFloat()` on returned values from `.css()`:

```
function changeOpacity() {
    $("#opacity").click(function () {
        var pippo = $('#pippo').css('opacity');
        var pluto = $('#pluto').css('opacity');
        $("#pippo").css("opacity", parseFloat(pippo) + 0.1);
        $("#pluto").css("opacity", parseFloat(pluto) - 0.1);

        console.log(pippo + 0.1);
    });
    $("#opacity2").click(function () {
        var pi = $('#pippo').css('opacity');
        var pl = $('#pluto').css('opacity');
        $("#pippo").css("opacity", parseFloat(pi) - 0.1);
        $("#pluto").css("opacity", parseFloat(pl) + 0.1);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLpe8yo1/7/) to demonstrate.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is correct, but the increment of 0.1 is too small to see a difference.

```
$( "#pippo").css( "opacity", pippo + 1 );
```

Something like the above code will help you see the difference more clearly.

Here's a fiddle to help see the difference better:

https://jsfiddle.net/k3xgLdrr/

Is this the kind of behavior you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla javascript option for future viewers.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var pippo = document.getElementById('pippo'),
        pluto = document.getElementById('pluto');
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'opacity') {
            pippo.style.opacity = Number(pippo.style.opacity) + 0.1;
            pluto.style.opacity = Number(pluto.style.opacity) - 0.1;
        }
        if (e.target.id == 'opacity2') {
            pippo.style.opacity = Number(pippo.style.opacity) - 0.1;
            pluto.style.opacity = Number(pluto.style.opacity) + 0.1;
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var pippo = document.getElementById('pippo'),
        pluto = document.getElementById('pluto');
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'opacity') {
            pippo.style.opacity = Number(pippo.style.opacity) + 0.1;
            pluto.style.opacity = Number(pluto.style.opacity) - 0.1;
        }
        if (e.target.id == 'opacity2') {
            pippo.style.opacity = Number(pippo.style.opacity) - 0.1;
            pluto.style.opacity = Number(pluto.style.opacity) + 0.1;
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

```css
#pippo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #e3ee31
}
#pluto {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #316fee
}
#opacity {
    width:40px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
#opacity2 {
    width:40px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="pippo" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
<div id="pluto" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
<div id="opacity">opacity</div>
<div id="opacity2">opacity2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `parseFloat()` when you get the current css opacity value.  This is because the `jQuery.css()` function returns a string rather than a number.

Check the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/gap9bh6b/1/

Comment: First time answering.  Legitimately curious, not looking to pick a fight -- why the down vote?

Comment: So no reason then?  Ok.